# Angular6 - How to check if Stripe payment was successful

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular6, stripe-payments

I am using Angular6, I am implementing Stripe payments in my app and using Google Cloud functions to run server side code. I can successfully get the payment to work, however, I am adding more logic to my function. In this function, I am processing the payment. My cloud function runs when I `onWrite` a document to `/payments/${this.userId}/payments` collection.

in the `.then` block of code, I want to the check if the Stripe payment was successful, and only if it was successful, then update the user's details in the database with the appropriate documents. However, I am not sure if this is the best method.

Also, currently, I am listening to changes in the document where the Stripe charge object will be returned, using `onSnapshot`, however, once it is succeeded, I don't want to listen to those value changes until another payment is made.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

```
processPayment(token: any, amount: number){

    const payment = { token, amount };
  this.paymentCollection.doc(`${this.userId}`).collection('payments').add({
            payment
        })
    .then(docRef => {
        this.docRefId = docRef.id;
        //if payment successful then add to the db of purchased lessons
        console.log(this.docRefId);
        this.db.collection("payments/"+`${this.userId}`+"/payments").doc(`${this.docRefId}`)
        .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
            if(doc.data().status === "succeeded"){

            const updatedBalance = this.balance - amount;;

            let writeBatch = firebase.firestore().batch();

            //CAN'T SEE CART CONTENTS

            for(let buyable of this.cartContents){
                let purchasedLessonsRef = this.afs.firestore.doc(`/purchased_lessons/${this.userId}/lessons/${buyable.b_id}`);
                writeBatch.update(purchasedLessonsRef, buyable);
            }

            //Update balance ref
            let userBalanceRef = this.afs.firestore.doc(`/users/${this.userId}`);
            writeBatch.update(userBalanceRef, {balance: updatedBalance});

            this.docRefId = null;

            return writeBatch.commit().then(function () {
                console.log("commiting batch")
            });
        }
    });

    console.log("finished function");
    })
.catch(error => console.error("Error adding document: ", error))
```

}